# Is MPMusicPlayerController working properly on iPod 5g?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am developing an application for iOS which works in two different modes, one of them plays music from the iPod library, and the other one synthesizes sounds (eg: pure tones).

In order to synthesize sounds I use an audio unit, so through its callback I can pass the desired signal. As far as sounds must be played at an specific volume, I set the device volume using iPodMusicPlayer.

The issue I see is that the first time the application is run on an iPod Touch 5g after turning it on, once the iPodMusicPlayer is used to set the volume of the device, applicationMusicPlayer will not respond to stop.

I came up with the following code. Runing it on an iPod Touch 5g after turning it on, music will not stop after touching stop.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
   mp.volume = 0.3;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playAction:(id)sender {
   MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
   MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
   [mp setQueueWithQuery:query];
   [mp play];
}

- (IBAction)stopAction:(id)sender {
   MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
   [mp stop];
}

@end
```

PS: It is also possible to reproduce the issue by entering the music app, the quitting it (double press on home button and quit music from the multitasking bar), and finally run the code above.

In the other devices I have tested so far (iPad 2nd and 3rd generation, iPod Touch 4 generation) the application works well.

Thanks in advance.